# How to can a std::array class member be statically asserted to be sorted in c++11?

Tags: c++, c++11

How can it be asserted, during compile time, that a `std::array<uint8_t, 3>` class member is sorted? This would allow it to be made `const`, use a `static_assert()` and not have to call `std::sort()` in the constructor.

In c++20 `std::is_sorted()` has become a constexpr, but is not available for prior versions.

Comment: What have you tried? implementation of constexpr `is_sorted` doesn't seem complicated.

Comment: However, source for the C++20 stdlib probably is available, so you could check that

Comment: A C++11 solution is probably impossible as `operator[]` is not `constexpr` in C++11, and `begin` / `end` member functions are only `constexpr` since C++17.

Comment: I had an invalid answer for this question, suggesting that you just adapt the code of `std::is_sorted()`. But - as @Holt pointed out, that won't work, because std::array _itself_ has some non-constexpr methods; and anything involving addresses probably precludes `constexpr`. So - I sadly agree with @Holt.

Comment: I disagree with @Holt, see my answer

Comment: @n314159 `std::get` is not `constexpr` in C++11. On [en.cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/get) there is a note *"The overloads are marked as constexpr since C++14. "*. If you look at N3337 (which is [the latest draft for C++11](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/links)), those are not `constexpr`.

Comment: Oh, dammit, I only looked at the top of the page where they are marked `constexpr`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here’s a proof of concept implementation that can be called directly on a `std::array`; making this more general (for other constexpr container types) is left as an exercise to the reader:

```
template <typename T, std::size_t N>
constexpr bool is_sorted(std::array<T, N> const& arr, std::size_t from) {
    return N - from == 0 or (arr[from - 1] <= arr[from] and is_sorted(arr, from + 1));
}

template <typename T, std::size_t N>
constexpr bool is_sorted(std::array<T, N> const& arr) {
    return N == 0 or is_sorted(arr, 1);
}
```

Comment: Comparing to einpoklum's code, I'm worried that this one isn't tail-recursive.

Comment: @Sneftel Does the compile time execution engine perform tail call optimisation before invoking `constexpr` functions? At a guess I doubt it, and since this targets tiny arrays the effect would be negligible anyway.

Comment: @Sneftel … but if it bothers you you can of course swap the last two conditional terms.

Answer (score 1):

**Disclaimer:** This requires C++14, since, as I have mentioned in the comments, you probably cannot implement a `constexpr` version of `is_sorted` for `std::array` prior to C++14 due to some operations on `std::array` not being `constexpr`<sup>1</sup> in C++11 (`operator[]` / `std::get<>`).

With a C++14 implementation, you can use a standard `for`-loop in your `constexpr` function and use this very simple implementation:

```
template<typename T, std::size_t N>
constexpr bool is_sorted(std::array<T, N> const &arr) {
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < arr.size() - 1; ++i) {
        if (arr[i] > arr[i + 1]) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Note that implementing `is_sorted` for other containers based on iterators (`array`, `span`, `string_view`) probably requires C++20 since there are no such things as [*ConstexprIterator*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/ConstexprIterator) prior to C++20.

<sub><sup>1</sup> It looks like gcc and clang provide these members as `constexpr` even with `-std=c++11`, so if this is okay for you, you can use one of the two other answers.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Not as nice as the other solution, but I wanted to show that this is possible (even if annoyingly so) in C++11 (building on @KonradRudolph's solution)

Edit: This is also just C++14, since `std::get` is only `constexpr` since then. The page on it on cppref has been confusing but has since then be fixed.

```cpp
#include <array>
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T, std::size_t N, std::size_t from>
constexpr typename std::enable_if<from == N, bool>::type
    is_sorted_impl(std::array<T, N> const &arr)
{
    return true;
}

template<typename T, std::size_t N, std::size_t from,
         class = typename std::enable_if<from<N>::type> 
constexpr bool is_sorted_impl(std::array<T, N> const &arr)
{
    return N - from == 0 or (std::get<from - 1>(arr) <= std::get<from>(arr) and
                             is_sorted_impl<T, N, from + 1>(arr));
}

template<typename T, std::size_t N>
constexpr bool is_sorted(std::array<T, N> const &arr)
{
    return N == 0 or is_sorted_impl<T, N, 1>(arr);
}

int main()
{
    constexpr std::array<int, 5> arr{1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    static_assert(is_sorted(arr), "test");
}
```

We use [`std::get`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/get) which was `constexpr` since it was introduced in C++14. To get around instantiating the `std::get<N>` (which gives obviously a compile time error) we specialize the function template for the case that `from == N` (which we need to do with `enable_if` since partial function template specializations are not allowed). Not nice, but possible.

On another note: @KonradRudolph's solution compiles under gcc and clang also with `-std=c++11 -pedantic`, altough it should not due to the `operator[]` not being `constexpr` is this a bug?

Comment: Hmm. [LWG issue 2443](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-defects.html#2443) covering this is marked Resolved and notes P0031R0, but I can't find an associated "N" document, and I don't know if this means a correction to the previous publication like some issue states do.